# Convert a place String to a CLLocation

Tags: ios, maps, cllocation

I'm having a bug with the convertion of an `NSString` (which contains a place from a `UITextField` input) to a `CLLocation`.

Here is the method supposed to process the convertion:

```
- (void)geoCodeForAddress:(NSString *)address {
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            CLPlacemark *placeMark = [placemarks lastObject];
            if (placeMark.location != nil) {
                self.actionLocation = placeMark.location;
            } else {
                self.actionLocation = nil;
            }
            if(self.event)
                [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    }];
}
```

My problem is, this method returns the wrong location for some specific strings. For instance, whenever I try to use "la patache paris" as an input, it returns a location in the wrong city though when I try the same exact string in Maps, it's finding the right place.

The method `geocodeAddressString:completionHandler:` is a `CoreLocation` method from the `CLGeocoder` class so there is no way I can see what's going on in it.

Would someone have some lead to find out why this is behaving weirdly ?

Thank you.

Comment: you are only taking last object, instead check the array for right place!

Comment: After debugging, it appears that only one place is returned anyway in the specific case I mentionned. I'll have this changed but this doesn't solve my problem sadly.